# Flask-wtf with trix-editor - How do I upload images

Tags: javascript, flask

I'm using Flask with one of my wtforms TextAreaFields mapped to Trix-Editor. All works well except for images using the built toolbar attach button.

I'd like to save the images to a directory on the backend and have a link to it in the trix-editor text. I'm saving this to a database.

I can make this work by adding an `<input type='file'/>`in my template like so:

```
  {{ form.description }}
   <trix-editor input="description"></trix-editor>
   <input type="file"/>
```

and the following javascript which I found somewhere as an example.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=> {
  let contentEl = document.querySelector('[name="description"]');
  let editorEl = document.querySelector('trix-editor');
  
  document.querySelector('input[type=file]').addEventListener('change', ({ target })=> {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener('load', ()=> {
      let image = document.createElement('img');
      image.src = reader.result;
      let tmp = document.createElement('div');
      tmp.appendChild(image);
      editorEl.editor.insertHTML(tmp.innerHTML);
      target.value = '';
    }, false);
    reader.readAsDataURL(target.files[0]);
  });
  
//  document.querySelector('[role="dump"]').addEventListener('click', ()=> {
//    document.querySelector('textarea').value = contentEl.value;
//  });

});
```

This saves the image embedded in the text. I don't want that because large images will take up a lot of space in the database and slow down loading of the editor when I load this data back into it from the database.

It is also ugly having the extra button when Trix has an attachment button in it's toolbar. So, I'd like to be able to click the toolbar button and have it upload or if that is too hard, have the built in toolbar button save the image embedded.

To save the images to a folder instead of embedded, the Trix-editor website says to use this javascript https://trix-editor.org/js/attachments.js

In this javascript I have to provide a HOST so I use

```
  var HOST = "http://localhost:5000/upload/"
```

and I set up a route in my flask file:

```
@tickets.post('/_upload/')
def upload():
    path = current_app.config['UPLOAD_DIRECTORY']

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            flash('No file part')
            return redirect(request.url)
        file = request.files['file']
        if file.filename == '':
            flash('No selected file')
            return redirect(request.url)
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            session["id"] = filename

            file.save(os.path.join(path, filename))
            return send_from_directory(path, filename)
```

I can select an image and it shows in the editor and it uploads to the directory on my backend as expected. But when I save the form the location of the image is not in in the document text (should be in there as something like `<img src="uploads/image.png>`

On the python console I see
"POST /_upload/ HTTP/1.1" 404 -

I can make this go away if I change the return on my route to something like `return "200"` But all the examples I have seen about uploading files have this or a render_template. I don't want to render a template so I'm using this although I don't really understand what it does.

I'm assuming I need to return something the javasript can use to embed the image link in the document. But I'm a total newbie (like you didn't figure that out already) so I don't know what to do for the return statement (assuming this is where the problem lies).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone else is trying to figure this out this is what I ended up doing.
Still needs a but of tweaking but works.
First I modified the example javascript for uploading to use Fetch instead of XMLHttpRequest

```
const editor = document.querySelector('trix-editor');
(function() {
    HOST = '/_upload/'

  addEventListener("trix-attachment-add", function(event) {
    if (event.attachment.file) {
      uploadFileAttachment(event.attachment)
    }
      // get rid of the progress bar as Fetch does not support progress yet
      // this code originally used XMLHttpRequest instead of Fetch
      event.attachment.setUploadProgress(100)
  })

  function uploadFileAttachment(attachment) {
    uploadFile(attachment.file, setAttributes)

    function setAttributes(attributes) {
      attachment.setAttributes(attributes)
      alert(attributes)
    }
  }

  function uploadFile(file, successCallback) {
    var key = createStorageKey(file)
    var formData = createFormData(key, file)

    fetch(HOST, {method: 'POST', body: formData}).then(function(response){
        response.json().then(function(data){
            alert(data.file, data.status)
            if (data.status == 204) {
                var attributes = {
                  url: HOST + key,
                  href: HOST + key + "?content-disposition=attachment"
                }
                console.log(attributes)
                successCallback(attributes)
            }
        })
  })
}


  function createStorageKey(file) {
    var date = new Date()
    var day = date.toISOString().slice(0,10)
    var name = date.getTime() + "-" + file.name
    return [day, name ].join("/")
  }

  function createFormData(key, file) {
    var data = new FormData()
    data.append("key", key)
    data.append("Content-Type", file.type)
    data.append("file", file)
    return data
  }
})();
```

Then modified my Flask route (which I'll refactor, this was just slapped together to make it work):

```
def upload():
    path = current_app.config['UPLOAD_DIRECTORY']
    new_path = request.form["key"].split('/')[0]
    file_upload_name = os.path.join(path, request.form["key"])
    print(file_upload_name)
    upload_path = os.path.join(path, new_path)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            flash('No file part')
            return redirect(request.url)

        file = request.files['file']

        if file.filename == '':
            flash('No selected file')
            return redirect(request.url)

        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            if not os.path.exists(upload_path):
                os.mkdir(upload_path)

            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            session["id"] = filename
            attachment = os.path.join(upload_path, filename)
            file.save(attachment)
            file.close()
            os.rename(attachment, file_upload_name)
            print(os.listdir(upload_path))
            return jsonify({'file': attachment, 'status': 204})
    return f'Nothing to see here'
```

Anyway, I hope that helps as it took me ages to figure out.